# vb.net datagridview checkbox loop error

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

i am currently looping through datagridview1 checkbox column (column1) and if the checkbox is checked, the value of cell from column3 must change.

My below code is working fine when `datagridview1.DefaultView.RowFilter = Nothing`
However it is not working when the `DefaultView.RowFilter` is enabled.

```
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
Dim isSelected As Boolean = Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells(0).Value)
If isSelected Then
row.Cells(3).Value = ComboBox2.Text  
End If
Next
```

Assume i have selected 5 checkboxes, but only 1 record will change and others 4 will remain same as it is. This happens only when the datagridview1 row filter is enabled.

Comment: What is the error? “it is not working” is not a good description of the problem. You may want to elaborate a bit more to describe what is not working as expected. In addition, you will want to let others know how the grid is set up… how is it filled. Is there a data source? Is the check box column part of that data source? This will make a difference as you stated the grid may be filtered. It is best to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example so others can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sorry JohnG, the grid is filled by access database through oledb adapter.
Check box column is added manually to the grid (Not a part of data source).
Comobox1 will filter the column named "Shift"

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun try...

```
For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 2
  'Your code here
Next
```

Note the -2 Apparently the grid is counting the last row with the star and nothing in it as a row.

Answer (score 0):

after research in google i am able to fix it.

```
Try

        For i = DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1

            If (DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value = True) Then

                DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("Shift").Value = ComboBox2.Text

            End If


        Next

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Thanks Guys!